# Finding the unit vector, and vector between two points

Tags: calculus, vectors

Given two points - $A(x_o, y_o, z_o)$, and $B(x_1, y_1, z_1)$

The points of course being arbitrary. I have to find $\vec{AB}$, and the unit vector $\frac{\vec{AB}}{||\vec{AB}||}$.

My method was the following:
\begin{align}
\vec{AB}&=\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}=<x_1,y_1,z_1>-<x_o,y_o,z_o> \\
\vec{AB}&= <x_1-x_0,y_1-y_o,z_1-z_o>
\end{align}
From here I can calculate the norm of the vector as the distance between the two points as the following.
The norm of the vector I got for the arbitrary points vector was the following:
$$\vec{u}=\frac{\vec{AB}}{||\vec{AB}||}=\frac{<x_1-x_0,y_1-y_o,z_1-z_o>}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_o)^2+(z_1-z_o)^2}}$$

Is my process the correct one for finding the vector $\vec{AB}$, and its unit vector?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: yeah it seems fair